# Uninterruptible Sleep handling with threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, multithreading, nfs

I am developing a Python program to replace a bash script my company used before. In the use case, there is a network mounted file system and this sometimes cause D state for the program (Uninterruptible sleep). I understand that this state is not salvageable maybe without fixing the mount. But I do not have the chance to fix the NFS now, I can if I am able to, will handle it.

So a process enters D state, it doesn't receive signals fine. But what if we use a thread. Can we still handle it by defining timeouts outside and kill the thread eventually. Or/and let the thread live until the main program ends, then kill it together with the main application.

Would a thread in D state (IO wait particularly), prevent the main application from being killed?

Is there another way that didn't come to my mind to handle endless IO waits with these kind of situations?

I was trying to simulate this situation to try it out, but could not find a way to induce it in Python in my local environment.

System is Ubuntu 20.04/22.04

Comment: Uninterruptible means uninterruptible - the thread with that state won't be killed. And yes, it's hard to reproduce that state + as some resources about process states say, D is the most dreaded state (D should normally be only momentary process state, as IO should be done quickly).

Comment: Also worth reading: why there's no way to kill the D state processes? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364100/why-cant-we-kill-uninterruptible-d-state-process

Comment: @h4z3 that's the thing actually, if in a different thread, the main thread maybe still able to receive signals. That's what I am exploring right now.

Comment: Would it make any sense to use a killable, subordinate _process_ to access the remote file?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I considered a child or spawned process to handle the critical section. But that process would still enter a D state. It would still allow the parent process to operate, but the child process would need to be dealt with later. It is certainly one of the options, just doesn't answer how threads behave in such a situation.